# Display image on page after upload

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, file-upload

I have a file upload on my page when the user uploads an image and clicks save this gets stored in the DB as a BYTE

When the view is return I pass back the BYTE to try and display the image but I keep getting the following error

**An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper'.**

I look at the inner exception which is as follows

**The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.**

I have used this code in the past in other projects which haven't caused an issue

This is my view pretty basic it does have other controls but for simplicity I'll only show the file upload

```
  @if (ViewBag.ImageData != null)
        {
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="WebAddress">
                    Preview
                </label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <img src="data:image;base64,@System.Convert.ToBase64String(Model.RetailerImage)" width="80" height="80" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }
```

And this is my controller

```
 [AuthorizeRolesAttribute(RoleType.Retailer)]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditStoreProfile(Retailer retailer)// ,string[] selectedBrands)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
            {
                var file = Request.Files[0];

                if (file != null)
                {
                    int ContentLength = file.ContentLength;

                    // Create Byte Array
                    byte[] bytImg = new byte[ContentLength];

                    // Read Uploaded file in Byte Array
                    file.InputStream.Read(bytImg, 0, ContentLength);

                    ViewBag.ImageData = bytImg;
                    retailer.RetailerImage = bytImg; // Store image byte in model ready for saving in the db, this will also be passed back to the view to be displayed as a preview
                }
            }

            try
            {
                //  retailer.RetailersProductBrands = GetRetailerBrands(selectedBrands, retailer.RetailerID);
                UnitOfWork.Retailer.Save(retailer);

                // UnitOfWork.RetailersProductBrandsRepository.DeleteExistingRetailerProductBrands(retailer.RetailerID);

                Retailer updatedRetails = UnitOfWork.Retailer.GetRetailer(retailer.RetailerID);
                //Email notification to administrator
                new MailController().NotifyStoreProfileUpdate(updatedRetails).Deliver();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, Constant.GenericErrorMessage);
                return View(retailer);
            }
        }

        PopulateViewBags();
        return View(retailer);
    }
```

But I'm not sure what's going wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HttpPostedFileBase`'s `InputStream` does not always return all the bytes in a single call to `Read`. Most likely you are getting the file only partially.

Use

```
var file = Request.Files[0];

if (file != null)
{
    MemoryStream memoryStream = file.InputStream as MemoryStream;
    if (memoryStream == null)
    {
        memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        file.InputStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    }
    byte[] bytImg = memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Am I right in saying the datatype for the image column in SQL should be varbinary(max) ?